# javascript array and objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I convert two arrays to the object?

My arrays:

```
arr1.push(3,2,3,6,11,7);        
arr2.push("num1","num2","num3","num4","num5","num6");
```

How to convert it to the object:

```
[{name:"num1", value:3}, {name:"num2", value:2}, {name:"num3", value:3}, {name:"num4", value:6}, {name:"num5", value:11}, {name:"num6", value:7}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try

```
 var obj = [];

 for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
     obj[i] = {name : arr1[i], value: arr2[i]};
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [],
    cv  = -1;

while(++cv < arr1.length) {
  arr.push({name:arr2[cv], value:arr1[cv]});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically has to merge both arrays.Assuming both arrays will always has equal length

```
arr1.push(3,2,3,6,11,7);        
arr2.push("num1","num2","num3","num4","num5","num6");

var obj  = [], i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    obj.push(arr1[i]+":"+arr2[i]);
}
// obj is now required object
```